# Using isdigit with if

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
 int f;
 printf("Type your age");
 scanf("%d", &f);
 if(!isdigit(f))
  {
   printf("Digit");
  }
  else
  {
   printf("Is not a digit");
  }
return 0;
}
```

No matter if a typed `6` or `a` always shows me the "Digit" message

Comment: `isdigit` is totally useless in this case since `scanf("%d")` will *only* scan in digits (with optional sign). Your best bet would be to just check the return value of `scanf` since it *gives* you the number of items successfully scanned (and check the sign of `f` if you don't want negatives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isdigit()` should be passed a `char` not an `int`.  And your if-else logic is reversed:

```
int main() {
    char f;

    printf("Type your age");
    scanf("%c", &f);

    if (isdigit(f)) {
        printf("Digit");
    } else {
        printf("Is not a digit");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this will only work for a single digit age.  Validating input is a major topic under the 'C' tag, a search will reveal many approaches to more robust validation.

Comment: But what if I'm `4xyzzy` years old? :-)

Comment: Then, once you have digested the above simple logic, you update your question or post another...or better yet search the many already existing answers....baby steps.

Comment: It should be passed an *int*, a char must be cast to an [unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321286/918959)

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is an integer specifier. Change `int f` to `char f` and parse as a character. You are always passing an `int` into `isdigit`, which is why it is always true.

Comment: In addition, the poster's logic is reversed. `if (!isdigit(f)) { printf('Digit');}`. You may want to point that out as well.

Comment: Looks like someone else beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no need to use `isdigit` *at all* here since `scanf` with the `%d` format specifier already guarantees that the characters will be digits with an optional leading sign. And there's a *separate* specifier to get rid of the leading sign, `%u`.

If what you input *isn't* of the correct format, `scanf` will tell you (since it returns the number of items successfully scanned).

So, for a simple solution, you can just use something like:

```
unsigned int age;
if (scanf("%u", &age) == 1) {
    puts("Not a valid age");
    return 1;
}
// Now it's a valid uint, though you may want to catch large values.
```

---

If you want *robust* code, you may have to put in a little more effort than a one-liner `scanf("%d")` - it's fine for one-time or throw-away programs but it has serious shortcomings for code intended to be used in real systems.

First, I would use the excellent string input routine in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf/2430310#2430310)<sup>(a)</sup> - it pretty much provides everything you need for prompted and checked user input.

Once you have the input as a string, `strtoul` allows you to do the same type of conversion as `scanf` but with the ability to also ensure there's no trailing rubbish on the line as well. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154275/how-to-get-unsigned-int-as-console-argument/13154368#13154368) (from the same author) provides the means for doing that.

Tying that all together, you can use something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Code to robustly get input from user.

#define OK       0      // Return codes - okay.
#define NO_INPUT 1      //              - no input given.
#define TOO_LONG 2      //              - input was too long.

static int getLine (
    char *prmpt,        // The prompt to use (NULL means no prompt).
    char *buff,         // The buffer to populate.
    size_t sz           // The size of the buffer.
) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.

    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.

    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.

    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}

// Code to check string is valid unsigned integer and within range.
// Returns true if it passed all checks, false otherwise.

static int validateStrAsUInt(
    char *str,                   // String to evaluate.
    unsigned int minVal,         // Minimum allowed value.
    unsigned int maxVal,         // Maximum allowed value.
    unsigned int *pResult        // Address of item to take value.
) {
    char *nextChar;
    unsigned long retVal = strtoul (str, &nextChar, 10);

    // Ensure we used the *whole* string and that it wasn't empty.

    if ((nextChar == str) || (*nextChar != '\0'))
        return 0;

    // Ensure it's within range.

    if ((retVal < minVal) || (retVal > maxVal))
        return 0;

    // It's okay, send it back to caller.

    *pResult = retVal;
    return 1;
}

// Code for testing above functions.

int main(void) {
    int retCode;
    unsigned int age;
    char buff[20];

    // Get it as string, detecting input errors.

    retCode = getLine ("Enter your age> ", buff, sizeof(buff));

    if (retCode == NO_INPUT) {
        printf ("\nError, no input given.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (retCode == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Error, input too long [%s]\n", buff);
        return 1;
    }

    // Check string is valid age.

    if (! validateStrAsUInt(buff, 0, 150, &age)) {
        printf("Not a valid age (0-150)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // It's okay, print and exit.

    printf("Age is valid: %u\n", age);
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I'm reliably informed the author is actually quite clever, and very good looking :-)